How to change default device_eui, epp_eui, app_key from the program?
I have my custom project on the LoRa RAK3172 module.
To set the DevEui, JoinEui & Appkey I have to set default as
uint8_t default_dev_eui[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
uint8_t default_join_eui[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
uint8_t default_app_key[16] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};


Which eventually gets stored in the NVM structure and then in the nvm_backup structure.
But is there any way how these can be changed without any change in the code?
I tried to pass the SeNVM structure into NVM structure. Which initially saves the data, but the nvm & nvm_backup overwrites the default data. Is there any function through which I can do it correctly?

With AT commands. See here.
AT+DEVEUI=?
AT+DEVEUI=1122334455667788
OK

AT+DEVEUI=1122334455667788
OK

AT+APPEUI=0102030405060708
OK

AT+APPEUI=?
AT+APPEUI=0102030405060708
OK

